# Overriding an internal method with Decorator Design Pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, decorator

I am writing an object-oriented code in which I am trying to use Decorator pattern to implement a variety of optimizations to be applied on a family of core classes at runtime. The main behaviour of core classes is a complex behaviour that is fully implemented in those classes, which indeed calls other internal methods to fulfill pieces of the task.
The decorators will only customize the internal methods which are called by the complex behaviour in core class.

Here is a pseudo-code of what I'm trying to reach:

```
interface I{
  complex();
  step1();
  step2();
}
```

```
class C implements I{
  complex(){
    ...
    this.step1();
    ...
    this.step2();
  }
  step1(){
    ...
  }
  step2(){
    ...
  }
}
```

```
abstract class Decorator implements I{
  I wrapped;
  constructor(I obj){
    this.wrapped = obj;
  }
  complex(){
    this.wrapped.complex();
  }
  step1(){
    this.wrapped.step1();
  }
  step2(){
    this.wrapped.step2();
  }
}
```

```
class ConcreteDecorator extends Decorator{
  constructor(I obj){
    super(obj);
  }
  step2(){
    ... // customizing step2()
  }
}
```

There are a variety of customizations possible which could be combined together, and that is the main reason I'm using decorator pattern. otherwise I'll get to create dozens to hundred subtypes for each possible combination of customizations.

Now if I try to create object of the decorated class:

```
x = new C();
y = new ConcreteDecorator(x);
y.complex();
```

I expect the `complex()` method to be executed form the wrapped core object, while using the overridden `step2()` method from decorator. But it does not work this way as the complex() method in abstract decorator directly calls the method on core object which indeed skips the overridden `step2()` in decorator.

My overall goal is to enable the decorators only overriding one or few of the `stepx()` methods and that would be invoked by the `complex()` method which is already implemented in the core object and invokes all the steps.

Could this functionality be implemented using Decorator design pattern at all? If yes how, and if not what is the appropriate design pattern for tackling this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: @Derefacto Yes! ```complex()``` is the main behaviour of the class. But to enable the different parts of the behaviour to be customized, I have created those smaller ```step()``` methods, where any of them could be overrided by subclasses/decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could resolve that problem with Strategy pattern, where the Strategy interface includes  the methods that are vary from class to class. Strategy interface may include as only one method as well as several depending on their nature.

```
interface IStrategy {
  step1(IData data);
  step2(IData data);
}

interface I {
  complex();
}

class C implements I {
  IData data

  constructor(IStrategy strategy) {}

  complex() {
    ...
    this.strategy.step1(this.data);
    ...
    this.strategy.step2(this.data);
  }
}

class S1 implements IStrategy {
  constructor(IStrategy strategy)

  step1(IData data) {
  }

  step2(IData data) {
  }
}

strategy1 = new S1();
c = new C(strategy1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a reasonable approach to tackle the problem, though it misses the hierarchical property of decorator pattern where you could combine multiple wrappers around the core class. Thanks anyway. 
I finally decided to implement the Chain of Responsibility pattern to have Middleware classes being chained to form the same effect as I was looking to implement via decorator pattern.

Comment: It would be interesting to see your solution. Could you add it to your question?